# Windows 10 Universal App Mobile Full Screen

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to allow my Windows 10 Universal app to utilize the screen space at the top of the phone where the Windows icons for Battery, Time, Wifi, etc. normally reside. I know it is possible because there are other apps that utilize that top space (for example: Candy Crush). Please see the screenshot of my app below. I am speaking of the region labeled "Unused Space."

[image]

I cannot find any MSDN documentation on this subject, and was concerned that it may have to do with my hard requirement to use a non-standard app bar. However, I created a project with a CommandBar and the unused space still exists. That said, I am at a loss as to how to regain that real estate.

Comment: [PreferedLaunchWindowingMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.preferredlaunchwindowingmode) enum.

Comment: https://www.eternalcoding.com/?p=1952

Comment: @Chris this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: No problem, cheers :)